# Ubuntu Box Sporadically Losing Time with Twitter API

Tags: python, unix, ubuntu, twitter-oauth, digital-ocean

I'm running a digitalocean Ubuntu box, and I am capturing Twitter's search API using python and the oauth2 module. My script works well for long periods of time, but after some time at an apparently random iterations of the script I get this error:

```
 "code":135,"message":"Timestamp out of bounds."
```

Several places suggest and confirm that this is a [time sync issue with my server and Twitter's API](https://twittercommunity.com/t/timestamp-out-of-bounds/287). Some have suggested that the two time's need to be within [30 seconds of each other at all times](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/issues/223). Is there anything I can be running, or adding to my python script that would prevent this intermittent time sync problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Digital Ocean publishes a [guide on setting up time synchronization](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-12-04) for their VPS services. It's the standard NTP setup in an easy to understand format. The original answer did not initiate a forced synchronization for clocks that varied further than ntpd would correct.

**Original:**

Twitter closely monitors time, as you have discovered. Thankfully, this is a well solved problem in computers.

For ubuntu, just run

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

which will install the daemon for Network Time Protocol, which will sync your computer's clock with the world. For more information on NTP (if you're curious), see the [wikipedia entry for NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still raising the error after some time.

Comment: I missed the part where you're using a VM, it could be your physical host is not keeping time correctly and is jumping or drifting enough to cause issues. You should contact your provider and ask them to look into it or move you to a different physical host

Comment: Upon further digging, following this tutorial configuring ntp especially for us servers worked. This was written by someone at digitalocean.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-12-04

@jumpandspintowin if you want to fold this into your answer, I'll accept it. Thanks for starting me in the right direction.